# Implementing 3 modals triggered by 3 buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 modal buttons. All three buttons have different inputs. But when I press the first button, everything is showing completely fine but when I press the 2nd and 3rd button, it shows the same results as the first button. Please have a look, I am attaching my code below.

**Extra:** It would be very helpful for me if you can suggest me, how I can put multiple photos stacked in the modal body without losing the shape of the modal. It will show a single photo in the modal body but if someone swap over the picture then the next picture will arrive. Thank you so much.

```js
// Modal
// Get DOM Elements
const modal = document.querySelector('#my-modal');
const modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close');

// Events
modalBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', openModal));
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

// Open
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Close
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Close If Outside Click
function outsideClick(e) {
  if (e.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
/* Modal section styling */

:root {
    --modal-duration: 1s;
    --modal-color: crimson;
  }
  
  .button {
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .button:hover {
    color: crimson;
    background: none;
  }
  
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  
  .modal-content {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 60%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    animation-name: modalopen;
    animation-duration: var(--modal-duration);
  }
  
  .modal-header h2,
  .modal-footer h3 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .modal-header {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .modal-body {
    padding: 10px 5px 1px 5px;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .modal-footer {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .close {
    color: #ccc;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  @keyframes modalopen {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!-- Modal Button 1 start -->
<button id="modal-btn" class="button">Parkit</button>
<div id="my-modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Vehicle Parking Application</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="https://thefinancialexpress.com.bd/uploads/1575560371.jpg" alt="Vehicle Parking Application" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <p>
      Footer
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 1 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 2 start -->
<button id="modal-btn2" class="button">IPDC IMS</button>
<div id="my-modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Asset Management System</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="#" alt="Asset Management System" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 2 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 3 start -->
<button id="modal-btn3" class="button">Gaming Website</button>
<div id="my-modal3" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Gaming Website</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 3 end -->
```

Comment: So you get the modal with the id `#my-modal` and you show him on `openModal` function. You never change the modal variable, so it will opens always the `#my-modal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would solve the  problem where every button triggering the same modal. You should be getting all modals and all buttons.

```js
// Modal
// Get DOM Elements
const modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
const modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

// Events
modalBtns.forEach((btn, index) =>
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => openModal(index))
);
closeBtns.forEach((btn, index) =>
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => closeModal(index))
);
// for closing when you click outside
modals.forEach((modal, index) =>
  modal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   if(e.target === e.currentTarget){
     closeModal(index);
   }
})
);

// Open
function openModal(index) {
  modals[index].style.display = "block";
}

// Close
function closeModal(index) {
  modals[index].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/* Modal section styling */

:root {
    --modal-duration: 1s;
    --modal-color: crimson;
  }
  
  .button {
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .button:hover {
    color: crimson;
    background: none;
  }
  
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  
  .modal-content {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 60%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    animation-name: modalopen;
    animation-duration: var(--modal-duration);
  }
  
  .modal-header h2,
  .modal-footer h3 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .modal-header {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .modal-body {
    padding: 10px 5px 1px 5px;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .modal-footer {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .close {
    color: #ccc;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  @keyframes modalopen {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!-- Modal Button 1 start -->
<button id="modal-btn" class="button">Parkit</button>
<div id="my-modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Vehicle Parking Application</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="https://thefinancialexpress.com.bd/uploads/1575560371.jpg" alt="Vehicle Parking Application" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <p>
      Footer
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 1 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 2 start -->
<button id="modal-btn2" class="button">IPDC IMS</button>
<div id="my-modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Asset Management System</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="#" alt="Asset Management System" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 2 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 3 start -->
<button id="modal-btn3" class="button">Gaming Website</button>
<div id="my-modal3" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Gaming Website</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 3 end -->
```

For the extra part where you want a slider inside your modals, I would suggest you to look at [swper.js](https://swiperjs.com), a JavaScript library that will allow you to set it up easily.

Comment: This will not work if the buttons are not in the correct order.

Comment: Yeah but he has them ordered.

Comment: The best solution its: Add a value tu each button, and this value will be the id of the modal, then on javascript get the value of clicked button and displays that value

Comment: That is exactly the correct way to do it, but I wanted to keep it simpler for him.

Comment: The solution of @yousoumar is working. Thanks a ton but clicking outside of the modal close the modal function is not working now. :(

Comment: Because I didn't add it @MinhazulIslamSaif. Give two minutes please if you want me to.

Comment: @MinhazulIslamSaif now you can close when you click outside.

Comment: @yousomar yes please, suggest me a complete solution when you are free <3

Comment: Curious is the `e.target === e.currentTarget` necessary

Comment: Yeah it tells whether we have clicked on the the modal itself or on one of its children.

Comment: @yousomar Thank you so much. I have got your updated solution <3

Comment: My pleasure. Though for the slider that you wanna implement  I suggest you to look at that link inside my response (I just added it below). I would want to implement it for you but have things to do right now and it should take some workaround.

Comment: @yousomar thank you. I'm going through the link and trying it for myself. If I face any problem, I might have to disturb you again, please don't get angry with me.

Comment: @yousoma can you please help me here?
How to make Swipers Image slider responsive and well fited in my modal?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/71212290/14518515?sem=2

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear to me. From what I infer, you are asking why the 3 buttons *Parkit*, *IPDC IMS*, and *Gaming Website* open the same modal.

That is because in your JS code, you're selecting one specific modal using its ID.

```
const modal = document.querySelector('#my-modal');
```

Instead, try selecting every modal using the class name `modal` and then in the `openModal` and `closeModal` instead of writing

```
modal.style.display = 'block';
modal.style.display = 'none';
```

Use the modal array you just created using `querySelectorAll` and write something like this

```
modal[i].style.display = 'block';
modal[i].style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you use `document.querySelector` and it only specify the first element.

Maybe try this one by specify the button use index which will make it work even you switch the order.

As long as you have the `class='modal'`, it will work.

```js
// Modal
// Get DOM Elements
const modal = document.querySelector('#my-modal');
const modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.close');

// Events
modalBtn.forEach((btn,index) => btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>openModal(index)));
closeBtn.forEach((btn,index) =>btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>closeModal(index)));
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

// Open
function openModal(i) {
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.modal')[i].style.display = 'block';
}

// Close
function closeModal(i) {
   document.querySelectorAll('.modal')[i].style.display = 'none';
}

// Close If Outside Click
function outsideClick(e) {
  if (e.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
/* Modal section styling */

:root {
    --modal-duration: 1s;
    --modal-color: crimson;
  }
  
  .button {
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .button:hover {
    color: crimson;
    background: none;
  }
  
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  
  .modal-content {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 60%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    animation-name: modalopen;
    animation-duration: var(--modal-duration);
  }
  
  .modal-header h2,
  .modal-footer h3 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .modal-header {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .modal-body {
    padding: 10px 5px 1px 5px;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .modal-footer {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .close {
    color: #ccc;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  @keyframes modalopen {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!-- Modal Button 1 start -->
<button id="modal-btn" class="button">Parkit</button>
<div id="my-modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Vehicle Parking Application</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="https://thefinancialexpress.com.bd/uploads/1575560371.jpg" alt="Vehicle Parking Application" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <p>
      Footer
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 1 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 2 start -->
<button id="modal-btn2" class="button">IPDC IMS</button>
<div id="my-modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Asset Management System</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="#" alt="Asset Management System" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 2 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 3 start -->
<button id="modal-btn3" class="button">Gaming Website</button>
<div id="my-modal3" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Gaming Website</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 3 end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is the easy way to do it. Just add a value to each button with the value of the modal id. Then save the opened model and everything works normaly.

```js
    var modal = "";
    const modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
    const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.close');

    // Events
    modalBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', openModal));
    closeBtn.forEach(close => close.addEventListener('click', closeModal)); 
    window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

    // Open
    function openModal(e) {
        modal = document.querySelector('#' + e.target.value);
        modal.style.display = 'block';
    }

    // Close
    function closeModal() {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
        modal = "";
    }

    // Close If Outside Click
    function outsideClick(e) {
        if (e.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

```css
:root {
    --modal-duration: 1s;
    --modal-color: crimson;
  }
  
  .button {
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .button:hover {
    color: crimson;
    background: none;
  }
  
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  
  .modal-content {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 60%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    animation-name: modalopen;
    animation-duration: var(--modal-duration);
  }
  
  .modal-header h2,
  .modal-footer h3 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .modal-header {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .modal-body {
    padding: 10px 5px 1px 5px;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .modal-footer {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .close {
    color: #ccc;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  @keyframes modalopen {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
   <button id="modal-btn" value="my-modal" class="button">Parkit</button>
    <div id="my-modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h3>Vehicle Parking Application</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="https://thefinancialexpress.com.bd/uploads/1575560371.jpg" alt="Vehicle Parking Application" class="responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <p>
            Footer
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Button 1 end -->

    <!-- Modal Button 2 start -->
    <button id="modal-btn2" value="my-modal2" class="button">IPDC IMS</button>
    <div id="my-modal2" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h3>Asset Management System</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="#" alt="Asset Management System" class="responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Button 2 end -->

    <!-- Modal Button 3 start -->
    <button id="modal-btn3" value="my-modal3" class="button">Gaming Website</button>
    <div id="my-modal3" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h3>Gaming Website</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```