# How to make Swipers Image slider responsive and well fited in my modal?

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

```js
// Modal
// Get DOM Elements
const modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
const modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

// Events
modalBtns.forEach((btn, index) =>
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => openModal(index))
);
closeBtns.forEach((btn, index) =>
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => closeModal(index))
);
// for closing when you click outside
modals.forEach((modal, index) =>
  modal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   if(e.target === e.currentTarget){
     closeModal(index);
   }
})
);

// Open
function openModal(index) {
  modals[index].style.display = "block";
}

// Close
function closeModal(index) {
  modals[index].style.display = "none";
}

// End Modal

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    centeredSlides: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
```

```css
/* Swiper styling */
.swiper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
}
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  

/* Modal section styling */

:root {
    --modal-duration: 1s;
    --modal-color: crimson;
  }
  
  .button {
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .button:hover {
    color: crimson;
    background: none;
  }
  
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  
  .modal-content {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 60%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    animation-name: modalopen;
    animation-duration: var(--modal-duration);
  }
  
  .modal-header h2,
  .modal-footer h3 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .modal-header {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .modal-body {
    padding: 10px 5px 1px 5px;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .modal-footer {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .close {
    color: #ccc;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  @keyframes modalopen {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<head>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Modal Button 1 start -->
<button id="modal-btn" class="button">Modal Button</button>
<div id="my-modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Vehicle Parking Web-Application</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
     <!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper">
<!-- Additional required wrapper -->
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
<!-- Slides -->
<div class="swiper-slide">
<img src="images/parkit.png" alt="Slide 1">
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
<img src="images/InverntoryMS.png" alt="Slide 2">
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
<img src="images/Airi.png" alt="Slide 3">
</div>
</div>
<!-- If we need pagination -->
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

I am making a portfolio for myself. I am facing a problem while using Swiper in my modal button. Images are not well fitted and responsive in my modal body. I have looked everywhere for the solution but can't find any proper solution anywhere. If anyone can help me with this, I will be grateful. I am attaching my code below.

Comment: In your css, you defined a fixed width of 800px for the ".swiper" class, change it to 100%.

Comment: @Alex Thanks a lot. It solved my problem <3

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code :

```
.swiper {
width: 800px;
height: 300px;
max-width: 100%;
```

}

you can add `max-width:100%` only